# Converting float64 to integer

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to convert a float64 column to integer.

```
print(df.sales.dtype)
print(df.sales)

float64
0        4.000
1        6.454
2        5.654
3       23.463

print(df.sales.fillna(0).astpye('int64'))

0        4
1        6
2        5
3       23
```

Whereas I am expecting `4000`, `6454`, `5654`, `23463`. The column can contain empty data that's why I use `fillna()`. How come `astype()` isn't working as expected?

Comment: you means `df['sales'].mul(1000).astype('int64')`?

Comment: Why would you expect that? `4.0`'s integer version would/should be `4`, not `4000`.

Comment: And when converting a floating number to an integer type everything after `.` is dropped. `5.654` when converted to integer would be `5`.

Comment: Thanks, my question is wrong then. Issue is with the data source, the sales is $4000 for first row, not $4.000 so I am trying to reconcile that by casting to integer. I suppose I'm more so looking to remove the `.` and then cast to int

Comment: Can you modify your post with your updated data?

Comment: The data is the same. I want a float64 4.000 to become a int64 4000 and float64 6.454 to become an int64 6454. No difference in the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sales': {0: 4.000, 1: 6.454, 2: float('nan'), 3:23.463, 4:5.654}})

df = (df.sales.fillna(0)*1000).astype(int)
#OR
df = (df.sales.fillna(0)*1000).astype(np.int64)

print(df)
```

output:

```
0     4000
1     6454
2        0
3    23463
4     5654
Name: sales, dtype: int64
```

**EDIT**:
if you want converting currency with $ to int64 you can try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sales': {0: '$4.000', 1: '$6.454', 2: float('nan'), 3: '$23.463', 4:'$5.654'}})

print(df)

df['sales'] = (((df['sales'].replace('[\$,]', '', regex=True).astype(float)).fillna(0))*1000).astype(np.int64) 

print();print(df)
```

output:

```
     sales
0   $4.000
1   $6.454
2      NaN
3  $23.463
4   $5.654

   sales
0   4000
1   6454
2      0
3  23463
4   5654
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments and if I understand correctly, you want:

1. to fill empty values with `0`.
2. to multiply the entire series by 1000.
3. to cast the result as `int64`.

Did I understand you correctly?

```
(df.sales.fillna(0) * 1000).astype(int64)
```